# Angular Material matDatepicker and Textarea as parts of a form

Tags: angular, forms, datepicker, angular-material, textarea

In my Angular app, I have a form. Into this form the user shall input the following:

1. Start Date
2. End Date
3. Some Text into a text area

I used the angular material "Datepicker" for the Start Date and End Date inputs:

```
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center"> 
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Select Start Date" ngModel #beginningInput="ngModel" name="beginning" type="date" required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error *ngIf="beginningInput.hasError('required')">
            Start date is required.
        </mat-error>   
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Select End Date" ngModel #endInput="ngModel" name="end" type="date" required>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error *ngIf="endInput.hasError('required')">
            End date is required.
        </mat-error>   
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
         <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea" ngModel #textInput="ngModel" name="description" ></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div class="gap"></div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="cancelButton" mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]>Cancel</button>
        <button class="submitButton" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="isDisabled">Submit</button>    
      </div>  
    </form>
```

When the form gets submitted, the Start Date, the End Date and the content of the text area are supposed to be saved and then processed. So in the .ts-file, there is the following code (which I include for completeness):

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

     this.beginning = form.value.beginning;
     this.end = form.value.end;
     this.description': form.value.description;

     //more code

}
```

However, the form stays invalid, that is, I cannot submit it, see the following screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure whether the following lines are correct, given what I want to do:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Select Start Date" ngModel #beginningInput="ngModel" name="beginning" type="date" required>
```

and

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Select End Date" ngModel #endInput="ngModel" name="end" type="date" required>
```

and

```
<textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea" ngModel #textInput="ngModel" name="description" ></textarea>
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Submit button stays `disabled` probably because you are never changing the value of `isDisabled` to false once the form is valid. You could instead do `[disabled]="f.invalid"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Submit` button stays `disabled` probably because you are never changing the value of `isDisabled` to false once the form is valid.

You could also directly check for form validity

```
[disabled]="f.invalid"
```

html code

```
<button class="submitButton" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="f.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: right ... thanks for the hint! (that was a stupid mistake)